# AngularJs Validation on Date doesn't work in IE and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

my problem is that when I tried to put required on my input type date which is  `birthdate` when I input date(4/29/2016) the required still shows and it won't let me submit my form. when I tried to remove the required attribute on my `birthdate` input it work fine... but what I want is to make the `birthdate` required.... I don't know why it won't work on date while it work just fine on other required inputs like `full_name`, `gender` and `email`

Since html5 doesn't work in Mozilla and IE
I use plugin for it to worked.

```
    <!--HTML5 Date and Month Input Compatibility-->
    <!-- cdn for modernizr-->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <!-- polyfiller file to detect and load polyfills -->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <!--end of compatibility-->
    <script>
      webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);
      webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
      webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
    </script>
```

**Submit Button**

```
    <button type="submit" form="form-customer"
            class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="cmd_insert_customer" ng-show="tab == 3">
     Insert Customer
    </button>
```

**FORM**

```
   <div class="row" ng-show="tab == 3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <form name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && insertCustomer(form)" id="form-customer" class="css-form" novalidate >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <img src="{{profilePic}}" id="profile_picture" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12"> 
                            <input type="file" name="image_path" id="image" class="form-control" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"  />
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <label>Full Name* 
                            <span class="required-label" ng-show="form.$submitted || form.full_name.$touched">
                                <span ng-show="form.full_name.$error.required">(Full Name is required.)</span>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="insertProfile.full_name" name="full_name" class="form-control" required="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <label>Gender*
                            <span class="required-label" ng-show="form.$submitted || form.gender.$touched">
                                <span ng-show="form.gender.$error.required">(Gender is required.)</span>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <select name="gender" class="form-control" ng-model="insertProfile.gender" required >
                            <option value ="">Select Gender</option>
                            <option value = "M">Male</option>
                            <option value = "F">Female</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <label>Birth Date*
                            <span class="required-label" ng-show="form.$submitted || form.birth_date.$touched">
                                <span ng-show="form.birth_date.$error.required">(Birthdate is required.)</span>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="date" name="birth_date" class="form-control" ng-model="insertProfile.birth_date" required />
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />  
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>Mobile #</label>
                    <input type="number" name="mobile" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="insertProfile.mobile" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>Email* 
                    <span class="required-label" ng-show="form.email.$error.email">(Invalid email address.)</span> 
                    <span class="required-label" ng-show="form.$submitted || form.email.$touched">
                        <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required">(Email is required.)</span>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="insertProfile.email" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="insertProfile.city" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <textarea name="address" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="insertProfile.address" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it doesn't work because AngularJS validates the type date with **ISO-8601 format** which is **yyyy-mm-dd**. So inputing the date with **yyyy/mm/dd** will result in invalid format that triggers the error. Please have a read in AngularJS documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[date]) for further information.

Comment: I happen to figure out what is going on.... when I add the plugin .... my input type date is being hide and  replace with input type text datepicker... when I select on the datepicker made by plugin it also copies the value on my input type date... however the date cannot validate the date pasted on it since the validation was being made by $touched(or similar behavior of keypress).... but I still don't have an answer... on how to fix this.. I'm searching if there's a similar way like ng-change validation... detect the change on my input type date

Comment: So I supposed that you're using `bootstrap-datepicker` library for the date input form? Could you please update your code that provides the usage of the plugins since I didn't got any clue on the datepicker.

Comment: I'm using html5 `input type= 'date'`... look at my question again... you can see a polyfill there... if the browser doesn't support my html5 date it replaces it with a datepicker..., but the other thing it should work when clicking submit button... since, I'm using `or` there... by `$touched` or `$submitted`....

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not aware that you're using polyfill for replacing the datepicker. I personally haven't tried using the polyfill plugins so I'm sorry that I couldn't give the best answer here. But I happened to try using `bootstrap-datepicker` with input type="date" and it works with required validation in firefox. Maybe you can give it a try using the library. If you're interested maybe I could update the example for you as well

Comment: okay i'll try searching for it.. thanks for the advice... I'm still scratching my head though... i'm on this for 3 hours..